# Getting error on implementing react-native with react-redux

Tags: windows, react-native, react-redux

I am new to react native.
I have setup project properly and able to run it in emulator. 
Now I want to use react-redux for my project. When I am running `npm install --save react-redux` I am getting following error.

```
+-- react-redux@5.0.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0

npm WARN react-redux@5.0.1 requires a peer of redux@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.
```

[image]

I am using ***Windows + Android Emulator***, got so many solution but all IOS based.
I have also tried to put manually.

My package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized it's not error, it is just missing dependent module.
Working fine after running `npm install --save redux`

It is also required two more dependency modules:

```
npm install --save redux-logger
npm install --save redux-thunk
```